# How to make the TextField to accept only date input in J2ME/JavaME

Tags: java-me, textfield

I have created a custom Date Class to handle bigger date and date from different calendar.
I would like to get date input from the user.The default DateField can't be used in this scenario since it can't handle big dates. So I would like to use the TextField instead.How ever, he existing constraints are not enough to constrain a date input like dd/mm/yyyy.
Can I create a custom input mask or any thing to constrain the DateField to accept only dd/mm/yyy  ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with DateField?  Also note the implementation varies between handsets, which device are you trying on?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create input mask for the TextField, the only way I could think of, is to create a custom component and handle the input yourself.

Or you could use three text fields beside each other and use NUMERIC constraint with maximum char size for each one.

Comment: how to place all of 3 textfields in one line?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you positive the DateField cant handle bigger formats?
2. Does J2me provide regular expressions, because that would definitely be the way to go for this.