# j2me set textfield constraints

Tags: java-me, constraints, textfield, midp, lcdui

I have to textfield in midlet. One for entering the date in format (DD.MM.YYYY), second for enternig only one letter. Is it possible to set such constraints that the first textfield accepts only numbers and dots and the second only one symbol?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make the TextField to accept only date input in J2ME/JavaME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776761/how-to-make-the-textfield-to-accept-only-date-input-in-j2me-javame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it accept only one symbol is very easy with [TextField API](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html) - just properly use `maxSize` parameter in constructor or `setMaxSize` method.

It is not possible to set such constraints that a textfield accepts only numbers and dots.

- To get an input like you describe, I would probably just use three `NUMERIC` text fields instead - for user to enter DD, MM and YYYY digits respectively

Comment: how can we place textfields in one line?

Comment: @Sergey MIDP API does not allow to force such placement for `TextField` objects. There's API to 'hint' the device that it is desired, see explanation in _Item Layout_ section in [lcdui Item API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html). Another option is to use 3rd party UI library like lwuit or j2me polish